# React HOC throws "Element type is invalid" error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, higher-order-components

I have a simple [portfolio project](https://github.com/daengdaengLee/portfolio) made with React. I want to use HOCs (higher-order-components), so I made a simple test HOC, but throws an error like this:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

[image: My error image]

My HOC is a simple `withTest` HOC like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const withTest = (prefix = '') => Comp => props => {
  console.log(`${prefix} This is the withTest HOC.`);
  return <Comp {...props} />;
};

export default withTest;
```

I use this HOC in my `App` component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Header, ProjectPage, AboutPage, Footer } from '../../components';
import { withTest } from '../../hoc';

const MyFooter = withTest('Footer Comp')(Footer);

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App container">
        <div className="mt-5">
          <Header />
        </div>
        <div className="my-5">
          <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={ProjectPage} />
          <Route path="/portfolio/about" component={AboutPage} />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-5">
          <MyFooter />
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why does this throw an error?

---

I found out where the error comes. But I don't know why it makes error.
If someone knows details, please help me.

I use `index.js` file for easy importing and exporting my components. It makes error.

- `index.js` for my components (`src/components/index.js`)

  ```
  import Component1 from './Component1';
  import Component2 from './Component2';

  export { Component1, Component2 };
  ```

  use:

  ```
  import { Component1, Component2 } from '../../components';
  ```

When I use like above. my `Component1` and `Component2` is `undefined` outside my `function App() {...}`.

App.js:

```
...
import { ..., Footer } from '../../components';

...  // here my Footer Component is undefined.

function App() {
    ...  // here my Footer Component is alive.
}

export default App;
```

So, When I just use

```
import Footer from '../../components/Footer';
```

I have no error.

App.js:

```
...
import Footer from '../../components/Footer';

...  // Now here my Footer Component is alive too.

function App() {
    ...  // here my Footer Component is alive.
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that I don't know the difference between them.
Why should I import my components directly?
Thanks for reading! Have a nice Coding!

Comment: Yes. If I don't use HOC and just use `<Footer />`, it works well. So I import my `Footer` correctly, maybe...

Comment: I cloned your repo and it worked perfectly. I see no issue.

Comment: I ended up here after running into the same issue you're describing: named exports (via index.js) cause my wrapped component to be undefined outside the component body, while default exports from within the wrapped component work perfectly. I'm guessing it has something to do with the order in which named and default exports are transpiled? If I learn for sure I'll post an answer here.